# Can session variables be set after page load

Tags: php, session

I am having a problem where my session variable is not being set ([Session variables only sets once the page has been refreshed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28094548/session-variables-only-sets-once-the-page-has-been-refreshed)) and I think the reason is that the page is loading before the PHP code has finished running. Resulting in the question: Can session variables be set/created after the page has loaded?

Comment: Do you have `session_start();` in the top of your document? Forgetting about session_start is surely the most common mistake in this topic. Show us some code... it's impossible to know what's going on unless you give us more info.

Comment: session_start() will fix it

Comment: yep I have session start, please read the comments on the post linked as I have not attained an answer/solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to the question is a resounding

## YES

Comment: LOL!! good answer. Not my DV though ;-) you've got some brass lol

Comment: _I went down, down, down and the flames went higher_

Comment: Ahhh Mr. Johnny Cash himself ;-) I saw him twice :-)) God bless his country western soul.